# Mysql get latest record/row based on another columns latest/max

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table like this

| id | name | version | ref_id | deleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | b | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | c | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | a | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | bb | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 6 | cc | 2 | 2 | 0 |

what I would like to achieve is to select the rows with the latest versions

| id | name | version | ref_id | deleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | b | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | a | 3 | 2 | 1 |

This is my original approach but is too slow for our system now:

```
select t.*
from (
    select ref_id, max(version) as version
    from table1
    group by ref_id
) latest
inner join table1 t on t.ref_id = latest.ref_id and t.version = latest.version
```

Is there a way to do something like:

```
select if(version = max(version), id, other columns) from table group by ref_id ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8 or later you can use `row_number` window function:

```
with cte as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by ref_id order by version desc) as rn
    from t
)
select *
from t
where rn = 1
```

For earlier versions of MySQL your existing approach is best but an alternate solution worth trying:

```
select *
from t
where (ref_id, version) in (
    select ref_id, max(version)
    from t
    group by ref_id
)
```